# Using Scanf with ObjC and iPhone

Tags: objective-c, iphone

trying to make an iPhone app and going through the tutorials and books recommended by those before me :) I'm trying to find information on the scanf/storing user input data from a text field into a variable which I can use later in my program. The text field is actually a number field, so I am trying to save the integers they input and not the text since there won't be any in my case. Am I on the wrong path here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what about if i am essentially trying
>   to save the input that is a number to
>   begin with

You want [NSNumberFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSNumberFormatter). The data formatters ( [Apple Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfNumberFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002368)) handle conversions to and from strings as well as formatting for output.

Answer (score 1):

I think rather than scanf, you're just looking to get the value from the text field as an NSString pointer.

If you use a UITextField in your interface, you can connect the UITextField to a member variable in your class by declaring the variable as an IBOutlet and connecting it in Interface Builder.

You can then access the text value as an NSString pointer by using [UITextField variable name].text.

There are many useful functions to work with NSStrings or convert the string to other datatypes such as integers.

Hope this helps!

Comment: what about if i am essentially trying to save the input that is a number to begin with?

Comment: You can use the intValue method on NSString to convert easily between a string and a number.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to get an integer out of a text field.

In your .h file:

```
#include <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
    UITextField *myTextField;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField;

- (IBAction)buttonPressed1:(id)sender;

@end
```

In your .m file:

```
#include "MyViewController.h"

@implementation MyViewController

@synthesize myTextField;

- (IBAction)buttonPressed1:(id)sender {
    NSString *textInMyTextField = myTextField.text;
    // textInMyTextField now contains the text in myTextField.

    NSInteger *numberInMyTextField = [textInMyTextField integerValue];
    // numberInMyTextField now contains an NSInteger based on the contents of myTextField

    // Do some stuff with numberInMyTextField...
}

- (void)dealloc {
    // Because we are retaining myTextField we need to make sure we release it when we're done with it.
    [myTextField release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

In interface builder, connect the myTextField outlet of your view controller to the text field you want to get the value from. Connect the buttonPressed1 action to the button.

Hope this helps!